# Log shipping Readonly/Standby executes Queries slow for some users

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I have a SQL Server database that is doing log shipping to another SQL Server instance, both servers have identical hardware. We have a reporting service that then runs reports against the readonly log shipped database. What we are experiencing is that when the application user executes a report at the readonly copy of the database, the query runs for a very long time. The same query executed against the primary database runs for about 5 minutes, and if you log in to the readonly database with another user we can get the results in 5 minutes as well, but for the application user which does exist at both the Primary and Secondary server correctly the report runs for more than an hour.

Any ideas on what to check?

Comment: Have parameters your reports? Did you check [parameter Sniffing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx) just guessing.

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Check the execution plans for differences..

Comment: No differences in actual execution plan on primary server to estimated execution plan on Read only server.  Can't get Actual with application or my SA user because those are the 2 that the report runs horribly slow on.

Comment: Are the reports sprocs or just client-side sql calls?

Comment: It's a proc that creates a dynamic piece of SQL.  We've pulled the Dynamic SQL out of the reports and found it's not an issue with the proc, as we can recreate the issue with just the SELECT that's generated.  We've also tracked the issue down to specific users...  When the SELECT is executed by User A the query runs and runs and runs, if it's executed as User B the query comes back in the expected time of 5 minutes.  We tried different combinations of permissions on a new user to try to recreate and identify the issue with the user causing the problem but so far haven't come up with anything.